# Many to many relationship issue with column name - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a problem with many to many relationship in EF core. I have the following models:

```cs
   public class Institution
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<InstitutionDepartment> InstitutionDepartments { get; set; }
    }


    public class InstitutionDepartment
    {
        [Column("Institution_Id")]
        public int InstitutionId { get; set; }
        [Column("Department_Id")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public Institution Institution { get; set; }
        public Departments Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class Departments
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<InstitutionDepartment> InstitutionDepartments { get; set; }
    }
```

I followed the many tutorials explaining how to correctly map these classes:

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<InstitutionDepartment>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.DepartmentId, x.InstitutionId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<InstitutionDepartment>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Institution)
        .WithMany(p => p.InstitutionDepartments)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.InstitutionId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<InstitutionDepartment>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Department)
        .WithMany(t => t.InstitutionDepartments)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.DepartmentId);
```

I wrote my query:

```
    var institutions = _context.Institutions
        .Include(i => i.InstitutionDepartments)
        .ThenInclude(id => id.Department);
```

But no matter what I do, I get the following error:
`Invalid column name 'InstitutionId'.`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here ? D:

**Note** I don't get the error if I don't write the `.ThenInclude(id => id.Department);` part.
But that make the data incomplete

Comment: @RicardoPeres he didn't rely on EF Core to handle many-to-many relationship for him. He did it himself using join table.

Comment: @Theo Benvenuti can you also provide the generated schema for those tables? I would like to see column names and FK constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from a line of code that I didn't deem relevant at the time (I'll know better next time)

This was in the `Institution` model without the `[NotMapped]` annotation:

```
        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<Departments> Departments
            => InstitutionDepartments?.Select(o => o.Department);
```

This was causing EF to look for a missing One to Many relationship between `Institution` and `Department`